# Deadlock with wait and notifyAll in Java - Threads don't wake up when notifyAll is called

Tags: java, multithreading

My program is supposed to print out the numbers from 1 to 10 in order, using threads (in order to learn threads).
The problem is that the program gets deadlocked. Why is that?

**I create 10 threads like this:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    new PrintThread(i).start();
}
```

**The thread class looks like this:**

```
class PrintThread extends Thread {
    int curr;
    static Integer prev;

    PrintThread(int curr) {
        this.curr = curr;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        if (prev == null) prev = curr - 1;

        while (curr != prev + 1) {

            System.out.println("Waiting...");

            try { wait(); }
            catch (InterruptedException e){ }

            System.out.println("Woke up!");
        }

        System.out.println(i);
        prev = curr;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
0

Waiting... (9 times)
```

Comment: You need to go back and read about threads and synchronization. You're creating 10 different objects which synchronize on themselves. No thread is blocking any other thread. Don't use `wait` and `notify` on `Thread` objects.

Comment: Making multiple threads behave like one single thread is not a good way to learn about multithreading. You should try implementing the producer consumer problem instead.

Comment: Thanks Chetan. I did that and after a couple of tries and exercises I feel much more confident with threads! _For the next guy wondering about this:_ Make the simplest possible producer/consumer program and then try doing some more advanced exercises!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wait(), notify() and notifyAll() are the methods of Object class. This should be called by the object(s) which is/are being shared among threads. Here I have written a small producer-consumer program which may clear your doubts on wait() & notify().

```
package com.mytest.example;

public class ThreadDemo {

    int message;
    String threadName;
    boolean consumed;

    ThreadDemo(int message, String threadName, boolean consumed) {
        this.setMessage(message);
        this.setThreadName(threadName);
        this.setConsumed(consumed);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadDemo demo = new ThreadDemo(0,"Main",true);

        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(demo));
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(demo));

        producer.start();
        consumer.start();

        try {
            consumer.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR:- "+e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Main() exit");
    }

    /**
     * @return the message
     */
    public int getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * @param message the message to set
     */
    public void setMessage(int message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    /**
     * @return the threadName
     */
    public String getThreadName() {
        return threadName;
    }

    /**
     * @param threadName the threadName to set
     */
    public void setThreadName(String threadName) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the contentAvailable
     */
    public boolean isConsumed() {
        return consumed;
    }

    /**
     * @param contentAvailable the contentAvailable to set
     */
    public void setConsumed(boolean consumed) {
        this.consumed = consumed;
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    ThreadDemo demo;

    Producer(ThreadDemo demo) {
        this.demo = demo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            produce(i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to produce a value in demo object & block the other threads which are waiting for demo object.
     * Once the producer finishes its task, it notifies all other waiting threads & releases the lock on demo object.
     * @param value
     */
    public void produce(int value) {
        synchronized (demo) {
            try {
                while(!demo.isConsumed()) {
                    demo.wait();
                }
                if(demo.isConsumed()) {
                    demo.setMessage(value);
                    demo.setThreadName("Producer");
                    demo.setConsumed(false);
                    System.out.println(demo.getThreadName()+": "+demo.getMessage());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    demo.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR:- "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    ThreadDemo demo;

    Consumer(ThreadDemo demo) {
        this.demo = demo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=1; i<=10;i++) {
            consume();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method checks whether any content available to consume from producer. If yes then it will acquire the lock 
     * on demo object and consumes the content. Once the content is consumed, it will releases the lock on demo object.
     */
    public void consume() {
        synchronized (demo) {
            try {
                while(demo.isConsumed()) {
                    demo.wait();
                }
                if(!demo.isConsumed()) {
                    demo.setThreadName("Consumer");
                    demo.setConsumed(true);
                    System.out.println(demo.getThreadName()+": "+demo.getMessage());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    demo.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR:- "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All your threads synchronize and wait on themselves. As a result, even if one thread would notify, that notify would reach no one as the other threads are waiting on a different monitor object (namely themselves). In this case all threads should synchronize and wait/notify on a common monitor object.

You should not use `wait` and `notify` on `Thread` objects at all as it might actually lead to a deadlock in the thread scheduling iirc.

As a side note: don't extend `Thread`, instead implement a `Runnable` and provide an instance of that `Runnable` as an argument to the constructor of `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Comment by @SotiriosDelimanolis explains the issue clearly. Wanted to point out some alternate approach to your problem, check the following program where one uses brute force logic of multiplying by time & other waits for a logic similar to yours without using `wait`.

```
import java.util.Set;        
public class ThreadChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new PrintThread2(i+1).start();
        }
    }

}

//Brute force method
class PrintThread extends Thread {
    int curr;
    static Integer prev;

    PrintThread(int curr) {
        this.curr = curr;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(curr*100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(curr);
    }
}

//Logic using Thread.sleep
class PrintThread2 extends Thread {
    int curr;
    static Integer prev=0;

    PrintThread2(int curr) {
        this.curr = curr;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        while(curr!=prev && curr-prev!=1){
            try {                   
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

         System.out.println(curr);
         prev = curr;      
         //Following is to debug the thread state
         Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
         for(Thread str: threadSet){
            System.out.println("Thread name:"+str.getName()+
                               " ; State:"+str.getState().toString());
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that as per Thread class is concerned no method other than join gurantees execution at a specific interval of time.
Hence different threads are invoked at different interval of time which is based on threads scheduler we no longer have complete control over these methods.

to be more precised i would suggest to watch these following videos to know more about threads.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_Ojfq-OIpM

Hope you could get your answer after watching these three videos

Answer (score 0):

I tried to be short.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class PrintThread implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Thread(new PrintThread(i)).start();
        }
    }

    private static final AtomicInteger nextToPrint = new AtomicInteger(0);  
    private final int curr;

    public PrintThread(int curr) {
        this.curr= curr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (nextToPrint) {
            while (nextToPrint.get() != curr) {
                try {
                    nextToPrint.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { /*do nothing*/ }
            }

            System.out.println(curr);   
            nextToPrint.incrementAndGet();
            nextToPrint.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```